# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabel' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox'

Tags: c#

In this line I am getting:

> Exception for "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabel' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox'

How to convert checkbox text to textbox text? What is the syntax?

My code:

```
RenameFormForPersonalData a
    = new RenameFormForPersonalData(currentSelectedButtonPersonal,1);

a.visible=true;
a.setCheck(editButtonToChecktext[((CheckBox)sender).Location.Y.ToString()].Text,
           editButtonToChecktext[((CheckBox)sender).Location.Y.ToString()]);
```

Comment: `sender` is a `LinkLabel` and you're trying to cast it to a `CheckBox`. Check you're subscribed to the right event.

Comment: for a "quick" fix not the best fix....cast to Control.And lee is absolutely right.You are casting to checkbox inside the linklabel handler..

Comment: Hi,thank you for your reply, Can You explain me, how to convert checkbox text to textbox text? urgently need pls..

Comment: this, code is linklabeltext to textboxtext, but  i need checkboxtext to textboxtext..

Comment: May you mark the correct answer given please so other people may find this useful.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the control that you is firing this event is a LinkLabel not a check box

```
if (sender is CheckBox)
{
    RenameFormForPersonalData a
= new RenameFormForPersonalData(currentSelectedButtonPersonal,1);

    a.visible=true;
    a.setCheck(editButtonToChecktext[((CheckBox)sender).Location.Y.ToString()].Text,
       editButtonToChecktext[((CheckBox)sender).Location.Y.ToString()]); 
}
```

You will see that this code won't fire but it will not throw an exception

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this:

```
a.setCheck(editButtonToChecktext[((CheckBox)sender).Location.Y.ToString()].Text,
           editButtonToChecktext[((LinkLabel)sender).Location.Y.ToString()]);
```

Or:

```
a.setCheck(editButtonToChecktext[((LinkLabel)sender).Location.Y.ToString()].Text,
           editButtonToChecktext[((CheckBox)sender).Location.Y.ToString()]);
```